# CSS3 columns: how to get proper horz padding with overflow-x?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm playing with CSS3 columns and trying to lay out content in a bunch of horizontal columns where, if the content is long enough, it creates a horizontally scrolling page. However, I **don't** want the content to butt right up against the left/right edges of the viewport but I **do** want the scrollbar to touch the left/right edges. I thought I could do this with padding, and initially it looked like it was working perfectly, until I scrolled all the way to the end of the content.

The code is pretty simple. HTML:

```
<section id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <p>And a bunch more paragraphs to overflow the viewport...</p>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content {
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;  
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#content p {
    /* just to make it easier to see the boundaries */
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

​
I also set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uu9Tv/.

I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to give the desired effect... margins on #content cause the scrollbars to not reach the sides of the viewport.

I also tried it a different way and basically let a wrapper div handle the overflow/scrolling and putting horizontal margins on the #content element, but it didn't seem to help at all.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vQLCz/.

Anyone able to shed any light on how to get some space on the far right of the columned content in a horizontally scrolling layout?

Comment: How about `margin-right` on the paragraphs instead of `column-gap` on `#content`? Here is a demo of that http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/uu9Tv/4/ . Or do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/uu9Tv/5/ ? I've done it by adding a wrapper and pseudo-elements on that wrapper as covers.

Comment: I could do it this way, yeah, but first of all, it feels wrong since the column-gap property is available. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes sense, but padding `section#content` doesn't apply to the overflowed content. Having columns makes this harder to see, so first look at my example `section#no-columns` in http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/wGKFa/. The section contains a paragraph with `nowrap`. Notice how the padding constrains the background color, but not the overflowing text.

When you add columns into the mix, the padding still doesn't apply to the overflowed paragraphs. A good alternative would be to put a margin on the `<p>`. This solution is limited. Since margin provides both the right "padding" and the "gap", they both have to be 50px.

Ah, the limits of CSS. CSS3 columns are nice, but limited....we can hope CSS4 will add some more elegant additions like `p:last-column { margin-right: 50px; }`.